# Fourier transformation of piece-wise function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let the function
$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0: &|x|>1\\
1: &|x| \leq 1
\end{cases}
$

$|x|$ is the euclidian norm of $x$.

My question is how we calculate $F(f)$? (the Fourier transformed).
I tried to do this:
 $$\begin{eqnarray}
 F(f)(\xi) &= & \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)
 \exp \big( -i \langle x,\xi \rangle \big) dx \\
 & = & \int_{[-1,1]^n} \exp \bigg( -i \sum_{k=1}^n
 x_k \xi_k \bigg) dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n =
 \prod_{k=1}^n \int_{-1}^1 \exp (-i x_k \xi_k) dx_k
 =\Pi_{i=1}^n \int_{-1}^1 [\cos(x_i \xi_i) - i \sin(x_i \xi_i)] dx_i
 \end{eqnarray}$$
But how I can conclude the calculation?

Comment: In yor notation, is $\lvert x\rvert=\max\limits_{i=1}^n\lvert x_i\rvert$ ? Because, in the usual euclidean norm $\lvert x\rvert =\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$, the closed ball $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\,\lvert x\rvert\le1\}$ is not $[-1,1]^n$.

Comment: yes, $|x|$ is the euclidian norm of x. Can you help me please.

Comment: As I already said, the integral is not over $[-1,1]^n$. The first passage is wrong.

Comment: so who's the good passage?